# Open the first file in a list of recursed folders

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to open the most recent picture from all my folders in my onedrive using powershell. I have already gotten to the point where i have a "list" which automatically sorts to newest and only gives me the "first 1" result.

I've tried implementing "Select-Object ().Open" but i don't see where i need to implement it. I can't get it to work.
I've also tried taking the directory and filename in variables to try and paste these together to then use these to open the picture.

This is my command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "(.jpg|.png)" -and $_.CreationTime.Year -ge "2019" -and $_.CreationTime.Month -ge "03"} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1
```

I'm expecting that there is a way to do this action and open this file in 1 command.

EDIT: I just discovered "Fullname" in the "Select-Object" function which is my directory and filename togheter. I still don't know how to implement ".Open" with this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$FirstFile = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "(.jpg|.png)" -and $_.CreationTime.Year -ge "2019" -and $_.CreationTime.Month -ge "03"} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1

Start-Process $FirstFile.FullName
```

You can also put the whole thing into a single line, though breaking the code will provide more readability -

```
Start-Process (Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "`
(.jpg|.png)" -and $_.CreationTime.Year -ge "2019" -and $_.CreationTime.Month -ge`
"03"} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1).FullName
```

Comment: Not exactly a one liner, but it works! Hopefully it's also good enough for the teacher.